# ADFS 3.0 Custom attribute in SAML token

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

I am setting up a relaying party trust (IDP) for an application a SP provides. Problem is that the SP requires a "customer ID" to be prefixed the username. E.g on-prem AD user john@company.com logges on and SP requires 001john@company.com to access the application.
How do i configure ADFS 3.0 to include the "customer id" in SAML token?

Error i receive now is: "The customer Id in the username john@company.com does not match the ones configued for the partner [001].
SP uses IBM FIM as federation solution.
Metadata is set up on both SP and IDP side.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append a string e.g.

c:[type == "http://someclaim"]
=> issue(type = "http://anotherclaim", value = "001" + c1.Value );

but there is not enough detail.

Do you always add "001" or does it vary?

Which claim do you want to alter?

**Update**

Have a normal LDAP rule that takes email and creates http://company.com/Temp1
(The dropdown is editable).

Then:

c:[type == "http://company.com/Temp1"]
=> issue(type = "http://company.com/Temp2", value = "001" + c.Value );

Then use a transform rule to transform  http://company.com/Temp2 to NameID with a format of email.

Comment: Their NameID Policy requires urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress. The 001 value is static for all users.

Comment: Thanks. Works fine now